# use polyglot package for Named Entity Recognition in hebrew

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, polyglot

I am trying to use the polyglot package for Named Entity Recognition in hebrew. 
this is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import polyglot
from polyglot.text import Text, Word
from polyglot.downloader import downloader
downloader.download("embeddings2.iw")
text = Text(u"in france and in germany")
print(type(text))
text2 = Text(u"נסעתי מירושלים לתל אביב")
print(type(text2))
print(text.entities)
print(text2.entities)
```

this is the output:

```
<class 'polyglot.text.Text'>
<class 'polyglot.text.Text'>
[I-LOC([u'france']), I-LOC([u'germany'])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/IPython/core/pyglot.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(text2.entities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\decorators.py", line 20, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\text.py", line 132, in entities
    for i, (w, tag) in enumerate(self.ne_chunker.annotate(self.words)):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\decorators.py", line 20, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\text.py", line 100, in ne_chunker
    return get_ner_tagger(lang=self.language.code)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\decorators.py", line 30, in memoizer
    cache[key] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\tag\base.py", line 191, in get_ner_tagger
    return NEChunker(lang=lang)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\tag\base.py", line 104, in __init__
    super(NEChunker, self).__init__(lang=lang)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\tag\base.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.predictor = self._load_network()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\tag\base.py", line 109, in _load_network
    self.embeddings = load_embeddings(self.lang, type='cw', normalize=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\decorators.py", line 30, in memoizer
    cache[key] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\load.py", line 61, in load_embeddings
    p = locate_resource(src_dir, lang)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\load.py", line 43, in locate_resource
    if downloader.status(package_id) != downloader.INSTALLED:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 738, in status
    info = self._info_or_id(info_or_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 508, in _info_or_id
    return self.info(info_or_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\polyglot\downloader.py", line 934, in info
    raise ValueError('Package %r not found in index' % id)
ValueError: Package u'embeddings2.iw' not found in index
```

The english worked but not the hebrew.
Whether I try to download the package `u'embeddings2.iw'`  or not I get:

```
ValueError: Package u'embeddings2.iw' not found in index
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it! 
It seems like a bug to me.
The language detection defined the language as `'iw'` which is the The former ISO 639 language code for Hebrew, and was changed to `'he'`.
The `text.entities` did not recognize the `iw` code, so i changes it like so:

```
text2.hint_language_code = 'he'
```